# How to create the link for a many to many relation in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to associate Rules and Records through a many to many association. 
The linking model is called Validation.
I created the models as explained in Rails Cast #47.

In the Rules view, I list candidates Records (extracted through a query).
When I click on a Record, I want to create the Validation and have it initialized with rule.id and record.id.

How to define the link_to statement in the Record index (embedded in the Rule show page)?
How to define the new function of the validations_controller ?

Are are my models:

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests
  has_many :records, through :requests
end


class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests
  has_many :business_rules, through :requests
end


class Validation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record        
  belongs_to :business_rule
end
```

The show view of the Rule looks like this:

```
RULE DEFINITION
    Name:
    Description:
    Condition:

CANDIDATE RECORDS:
    Identifier   |   Name    | Description                | Owner
        1015        Ozone      Molecule                     TEDE
        1089        Lithium    Atom                         RICO
      110236        Dipeptide  Molecule                     MARCO
...
```

So the link_to should be created on the Record identifier to create the Validation through the new function of the validations_controller. And the Validation form is to be displayed for the user to fill it.

I hope this is clear enough ...

Thanks for your help !

Best regards,

Fred

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure I am understanding you 100% but Ill give it a shot.  To get the resource ids for each of those you will want to nest the resources in your `routes.rb` file. This will allow you to construct complex URLs that contain the ids you need. Something like:

```
resources :rules do
  resources :requests
end
```

Then if you run `rake:routes` you will see the url something like `/rules/{id}/requests/{request_id}`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint CWitty. My question focuses more on: how do I spell the URL to solve my 3 parts problem ?